# How to remove first occurence of an element in array in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I want to get something like this

Input :

```
[2,1,4,1,1,3]
```

Output:

```
[2,4,1,1,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT
    data.1 AS value,
    data.2 AS array,
    arrayFilter((x, groupPosition) -> groupPosition != 1 OR x != value, array, arrayEnumerateUniq(array)) AS result
FROM
(
    /* test data, where the first item is value to apply the filter, the second one is array */
    SELECT arrayJoin([
      (1, [2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3]), /* exclude the first occurrence of 1 */
      (2, [2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3]), /* exclude the first occurrence of 2 */
      (3, [2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3]), /* .. */
      (4, [2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3]),
      (5, [2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3]),
      (1, []),
      (1, [1]),      
      (1, [1, 1, 1])
      ]) AS data
)

/* Result:
┌─value─┬─array─────────┬─result────────┐
│     1 │ [2,1,4,1,1,3] │ [2,4,1,1,3]   │
│     2 │ [2,1,4,1,1,3] │ [1,4,1,1,3]   │
│     3 │ [2,1,4,1,1,3] │ [2,1,4,1,1]   │
│     4 │ [2,1,4,1,1,3] │ [2,1,1,1,3]   │
│     5 │ [2,1,4,1,1,3] │ [2,1,4,1,1,3] │
│     1 │ []            │ []            │
│     1 │ [1]           │ []            │
│     1 │ [1,1,1]       │ [1,1]         │
└───────┴───────────────┴───────────────┘
*/
```